# Does 3.0 have any limits to number of asset libraries?

Tags: asset-browser

In *Preferences* in *File Paths* there is a list a of folders  for the asset libraries. Is there a hard limit on how many folders you can have in it?

Comment: That's a list of **folders** not files. All Blend files within each folder in the list (and ones below it) will be scanned for assets. The asset library system docs are [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/asset_libraries/introduction.html).

Comment: Whats limit on folders

Comment: I think the answer is no, there is no hardcoded limit. Or rather, you'll hit your machine limits before the software theoretical limits. I sense you ought to be asking another question, could you elaborate on why exactly you are worried about this limit ?

Comment: i have hundreds things filled 1 per file. dozens folders 1 per source. have to mark each so wonder best way to do.

Comment: I agree with @Gorgious. There's no set limit shown in the docs. It's really a case of being sensible and not (for instance) downloading and adding every HDRI from Polyhaven to your assets in case you ever want to use one!

Comment: you know or you guess? some hard limits in prefs like undo so why not this? is not about sensible. is about many project many years mean many things collected. maybe browser not useful large collection

Comment: Well it's really hard to answer. It's like asking, [How many folders can I put in one folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/1624192/how-many-folders-can-i-put-in-one-windows-folder) ? I'm sure the theoretical source code limit is way higher than the one you'll hit with your machine. But I don't think you're supposed to have more than a few dozens asset library paths in your preferences at most. The number of folders in these asset libraries though, will be limited by your computer's capacity to read the folder contents and blend files, and the algorithm is indeed managed by the software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to want an authoritative answer:

Short answer:  No, there is no hard limit, because libraries are represented internally in a data type that has no hard limit.

Detailed answer:

- The code that implements the preferences panel for asset libraries can be found in `space_userpref.py` starting at line 1839.
- `paths.asset_libraries` is the member that contains the collection of asset libraries.
- It is an instance of `USERPREF_PT_file_paths_asset_libraries`, a class that you can find out about by looking at the [Preferences File Paths](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PreferencesFilePaths.html) entry in the manual; where you will find the entry for [asset_libraries](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PreferencesFilePaths.html#bpy.types.PreferencesFilePaths.asset_libraries)
- `asset_libraries` is a

> Type: bpy_prop_collection of UserAssetLibrary

Comment on your underlying question:

The manual's [Asset Library Introduction](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/asset_libraries/introduction.html) contains a warning:

> Note that this scanning process may take a while, depending on the number of blend-files and the number of assets contained within them. Blender 3.1 will add indexing of these assets, greatly improving the speed at which an asset library can be reopened. See [T91406](https://developer.blender.org/T91406) for more info.

In plain English, this suggests that more assets per file and fewer files per folder is probably a good idea, at least until 3.1.

I would recommend, perhaps, one file per source with all of the assets from that source in the file; but note that I haven't set up my own asset libraries yet, so that's based only on the warning.